# error message when uploading file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The file uploading is working properly using ruby on rails. Now i need to validate my uploading. It should validate and display error message when no file is selected after clicking upload. Please help me with a code for this error validation.

My view file is (uploadfile.html.erb):

```
     <h1>File Upload</h1>
     <%= form_tag({action: :uploadFile}, multipart: true) do %>
     <p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label>
     <%= error_messages_for :data_file %>
     <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
     <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
     <%end%>
```

My controller file is (upload_controller.rb):

```
    class UploadController < ApplicationController
    def uploadFile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
    end
    end
```

My model file is (data_file.rb):

```
    class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :upload
    validates_attachment_presence :upload unless :upload
    def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
    end
    end
```

Comment: if in case you want to handle in controller action use `if params[:upload].present? and params[:upload][:datafile].present?`

Comment: @Nithin i need to show alert message like "no file chosen please choose file" after clicking upload

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem,you can do like this in your Model.

```
validates_attachment_presence :datafile unless :datafile
```

It checks the existence of uploaded file.

**Update**

For displaying the error messages,just add this line to your form

```
<%= error_messages_for :upload_file %> #Assuming your model name is `upload_file`
```

Comment: everything good.but i need the error message should be displayed when no file is chosen.

Comment: i'm getting this error " undefined method `error_messages_for' for #<#<Class:0x3217050>:0x2a9b1f0> "

Comment: i posted my full coding

Comment: @user3279260 Try moving this line `<%= error_messages_for :data_file %>` just below the `form_tag` line

Comment: @user3279260 Now i get it.Its because you added the validation in the wrong model.it should be in Upload model.

Comment: sorry i cant understand. can you edit and post the code please ?

Comment: @user3279260 Just add this line `validates_attachment_presence :datafile unless :datafile` to your `Upload` model.Right now you added it in the `DataFile` model which is wrong.

Comment: I added.should I have to change my model name to  " upload.rb "

Comment: @user3279260 No! don't you have a model called `Upload`?

Comment: @user3279260 You should be having it.Without having `Upload` model then how come there is `upload_controller`?

Comment: model > rails g model data_file                                               controller > rails g controller upload like that i created

Comment: @user3279260 Okay, try renaming the model class to `Upload` and the file name to `upload.rb`

Comment: i renamed to upload.rb,still i'm getting error "undefined method `error_messages_for'".

Comment: everything working well.i need to show alert message like "no file chosen please choose file" after clicking upload

Comment: @user3279260 For that you need to add javascript. Try asking the problem with another question hi-lighting the javascript. For now this is the answer for your question.Please accept it and move on.