# getting image name or path from file field control into controller's page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `file field` control on my page like below:

```
<h2><%= @blah %>hello</h2>
    <%= form_for(:ImageUpload, :html => { :id => "imageupload" }) do |f| %>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="92%">
                <tr>
                   <td align="center">
                      <div class="button" style="margin-right:60px;">
                        <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
                      </div>
                   </td>
                </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
```

And I want to use `file field` for getting image and set into user profile, for that I want to get `image name` or `image path` and i am using below:

```
  def create
    @blah = params[:upload]
    upload_img = params[:upload]
    render 'new'
  end
```

But in the `@blah` variable, it gets me like this `{"datafile"=>"index.jpg"}hello`, How do I am getting image name or path from `file field` control into a controller's page, Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Use carrierwave or paperclip gem to make it simple. i do prefer carrierwave. understandable documentation

Comment: `multipart=>true` is missed out, check [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934199/error-message-when-uploading-file-in-ruby-on-rails)  you are missing file operation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be missing something here

```
@blah = params[:upload]["datafile"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gem  carrierwave

Otherwise u need to do file operations to save the image get the images. Make your work simple.

See documentation here http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/

Answer (score 0):

Please add in your form_for tag  **multipart: true** option.

Syntax:-

```
<h2><%= @blah %>hello</h2>
<%= form_for(:ImageUpload, :html => { :id => "imageupload",:mulitipart => true}) do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="92%">
            <tr>
               <td align="center">
                  <div class="button" style="margin-right:60px;">
                    <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```